# I have deployed my Django website in 000webhosthost for free but its not working

Tags: python, django, deployment

I have deployed my Django 1.7 website in 000webhosthost for free but its not working. It is deployed with no error but it is not working properly. This is link of  [My website on 000webhost](http://drchitradhawale.netau.net/) and its snapshot is-

---

[image]
Here i can find the problem is static files are not including and include function is not working.

> My index.html program is-

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'webpage/style.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div>
{% include "webpage/header.html" %} 
</div>

  
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div col-md-12 .col-md-offset-3>
     <h3>Key Achievements</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>Ph.D. in Computer Science</li>
      <li> Incharge Principal S.P. College</li>
      <li>Guest Lectures for Research and finishing schools  </li>
      <li>Researcher in image processing domain of computer science </li>
      <li>Head of MCA Department at P.R.Patil Group of Educational Institutes, Amrvavati</li>
   </ul>
    </div>

   </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="">
<img src="{% static 'webpage/images/chitraMam.jpg' %}" alt="My image" width="60%"  height="10% "/>
         </div>
 </div>

<hr> 
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <h5 align="center"><strong>Teaching</strong></h6>
         <ul><small>
      <li>Having more than 2-decades of academic experience including :teaching (PG,PG) ,research and administration.</li>
      <li>Served as a Professor in computer department of  symbiosis International University, Pune-2009-2010 </li>
      <li>Sr  Lecturer at  in MCA department from 2008-2009 HVMPM, Amravati., </li>
      <li>Lecturer   from 2003 at HVMPM, Amravati.</li>
   </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <h5 align="center"><strong>Research</strong></h6>
         <ul>
      <li>Registered supervisor for Ph.D in Computer Science at Amravati university, Nagpur University, Symbiosis International University.</li>
      <li>6 phd students working and 03 awarded phd degree.</li>
   </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <h5 align="center"><strong>Invited Talks</strong></h6>
         <ul>
      <li>Ph.D. in Computer Science</li>
      <li> Incharge Principal S.P. College</li>
      <li>Guest Lectures for Research and finishing schools  </li>
      <li>Researcher in image processing domain of computer science </li>
      <li>Head of MCA Department at P.R.Patil Group of Educational Institutes, Amrvavati</li>
   </ul>
    </div>
 </div>


</div>
</div>   <!--Main div -->
</div>
```

Anybody please help.

Comment: So `collectstatic` isn't working? If not, you should elaborate: what's the error, what are your static settings, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to plan comparison on http://www.000webhost.com/, their free plan does not include python support. The screenshot you provided confirms this hypothesis, since django templates are served as ordinary html files.

If you are looking for a free hosting for django sites, take a look at https://www.heroku.com/. Their free plan is fairly limited, but allows you to host a simple django page.